# What are great combinations for games?

Tags: game-dev-tycoon

In Game Dev Tycoon, you get an experience multiplier and bonus to your review scores by creating games utilising a 'Good' or 'Great' Combination of genre and game type, along with aiming the game at the correct target audience. For example, Military and Simulation is a 'Great' Combo.

What are other great combinations for creating games?

Comment: knowing game dev story, if this is anything similar there may be too many combinations to list

Answer (score 15, accepted):

There are a very large amount of Great Combinations. Game Dev Tycoon shares most of its Great Combinations with Game Dev Story. An incomplete list follows:

- Airplane / Casual
- Airplane / Simulation
- Airplane / Action
- Aliens / Action
- Alternate History / RPG
- Business / Simulation
- City / Simulation
- City / Strategy
- Comedy / Casual
- Cyberpunk / Action
- Cyberpunk / RPG
- Dance / Casual
- Dance / Simulation
- Detective / Adventure
- Dungeon / RPG
- Dungeon / Strategy
- Evolution / Simulation
- Fantasy / Adventure
- Fantasy / RPG
- Fashion / Casual
- Game Dev / Simulation
- Government / Simulation
- Government / Strategy
- Hacking / Simulation
- Hacking / Strategy / Mature
- History / Strategy
- Horror / Action
- Hospital / Simulation
- Hunting / Action
- Law / Adventure
- Law / Simulation
- Life / Adventure
- Life / Simulation
- Martial Arts / Action
- Medieval / Action
- Medieval / RPG / Young / Everyone
- Medieval / Strategy / Young / Everyone
- Military / Action
- Military / Strategy
- Movies / Casual
- Movies / Simulation
- Music / Casual
- Music / Simulation
- Mystery / Adventure
- Ninja / Action
- Pirate / Adventure
- Post Apocalyptic / Action / Mature
- Post Apocalyptic / RPG / Mature
- Prison / Action
- Prison / Adventure
- Racing / Casual / Young / Everyone
- Racing / Simulation / Young / Everyone
- Rhythm / Casual
- Rhythm / Simulation
- Romance / Adventure
- School / Adventure
- School / Simulation
- Sci-Fi / Adventure
- Sci-Fi / RPG
- Space / Action
- Space / Simulation
- Space / Strategy
- Sports / Action
- Sports / Casual
- Sports / Simulation
- Spy / Action
- Spy / Adventure
- Spy / RPG
- Startups / Simulation
- Superheroes / Action / Young
- Surgery / Simulation
- Time Travel / Adventure
- Transport / Strategy
- UFO / Action
- UFO / Strategy
- Vampire / Action
- Vampire / RPG
- Virtual Pet / Casual
- Virtual Pet / Simulation
- Vocabulary / Casual
- Werewolf / Action
- Werewolf / RPG
- Wild West / RPG
- Zombies / Action

[Initial source](http://gamedevtycoon.wikia.com/wiki/Game_Combinations#Perfect_Genre_Combos)

Comment: To anyone who might add to the list: *Please, please, please* keep it in alphabetical order. I may go insane otherwise.

Comment: What about 2 genre mixs?

Comment: @BaileyRowland For 2 genre mixes, I took the list and found whatever had two genres listen for it and then combined them, it seemed to work well.

Comment: Add that to the answer.

Comment: Airplane / Action is also a great comb.