# Which genre fits or works well with which platform?

Tags: game-dev-tycoon

I occasionally get reviews like:
[image: RPG games work well on Playsystem 2.]

It seems that each genre has its own popularity on each platform. Choice of genre, relative to platform, affects the review scores.

**How do I know which game genre fits or works well with which platform?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a chart of fitting and well-fitting platforms for each game genre:

[image: chart of fitting and well-fitting platforms for each game genre]

<sup>Source: [Game Dev Tycoon wiki, "Game Development" article](http://gamedevtycoon.wikia.com/wiki/Game_Development)</sup>

Answer (score 7):

**KEY:** `++` = best, `+` = good, otherwise, avoid these combinations

```
               Action   Adventure   RPG   Simulation   Strategy   Casual
PC               +           +       +        +            +         +
Govodore 64      +           +       +        +            +         +
TES              +
Master V         +
Gameling         +                  ++                               +
Vena Gear        +                  ++
Vena Oasis       +                  ++
Super TES        +
Playsystem       +                  ++
TES 64           +                  
DreamVast        +          ++
Playsystem 2     +                  ++                               +
mBox             ++          +
Game Sphere      +
GS                                   +        ++           ++        ++
PPS              +                  ++
mBox 360         +                   +                               ++
Nuu                                           +                      +
Playsystem 3     +                   +
grPhone                              +        ++           ++        ++
grPad                                +        ++           ++        ++
mPad                                          ++           +         ++
Wuu                                           ++                     +
mBox Next        ++                  +                               ++
Playsystem 4     +                   +
Custom Console   ++                  +                               ++
```

This table is generated from [raw data collected from the game](http://gamedevtycoon.wikia.com/wiki/Raw_Data_for_Review_Algorithm#Platform_Genre_Combinations).

In addition to the above table, [certain combinations of game](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/115581/27134) work better when targeted at specific audiences, for example Post Apocalyptic/Action and Post Apocalyptic/RPG games are best suited when targeted towards more mature audiences.

Comment: That's odd; in my current game at Y31, the PC has "Casual" as ---. Either the upgraded PC has different stats, or there's been a tweak.